# Kubernetes cluster without kubernetes Master

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes cluster working fine. I have one `master` node and 5 `worker` nodes, and all these are running pods. When all the nodes are on and if the kubernetes master goes down/ powered off, will the worker nodes keep working as normally.?

If `master` node is down and one of the `worker` node also goes down and then come back online after sometime. Then will the pod automatically be started on that worker as the `master` node is still down.?

Comment: You definitely can find answer here, but, why don't you test this cases by yourself? If you are going to learn Kubernetes you should be able to create environments for testing the functionality

Comment: Thankyou but I can alter anything in production environment. I am setting it up local cluster which will take sometime so thought of asking.

Comment: It would be great if you question was like: "i'd like to test  the behaviour of kubernetes in different scenarios. What is the best way to create test environment for this?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When all the nodes are on and if the kubernetes master goes down/ powered off, will the worker nodes keep working as normally.?

Yes, they will work in their last state.

> If `master` node is down and one of the `worker` node also goes down and then come back online after sometime. Then will the pod automatically be started on that worker as the `master` node is still down.?

No.

As you can read in [Kubernetes Components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/) section:

`Master components provide the cluster’s control plane. Master components make global decisions about the cluster (for example, scheduling), and detecting and responding to cluster events (starting up a new pod when a replication controller’s ‘replicas’ field is unsatisfied).`